# R: Automation of variables names in a Model

Tags: r

Hello How can I automate the variable names to change it to other variables.

```
#Variable names
d <- data.frame(Bound_Count = 1, Days_diff_Eff_Subm_2 = 2, TR_BS_BROKER_ID_360_M = 3, 
                TR_BS_BROKER_ID_360_2 = 4, RURALPOP_P_CWR_2 = 5, RURALPOP_P_CWR_M = 6, PIP_Flag = 7, 
                TR_B_BROKER_ID_360 = 8, TR_SCW_BROKER_ID_360 = 9, TR_BS_BROKER_INDIVIDUAL_720_2 = 10,
                TR_BS_BROKER_INDIVIDUAL_720_M = 11, Resolved_Conflict = 12, 
                Priority_2 = 13)
# exclude dependent variable
allvariables <- names(d)[-1] 
# container for models
listOfModels <- vector("list", length(allvariables))
# loop over variables
for (i in seq_along(allvariables)) {
  # exclude variable i
  currentvariable <- allvariables[-i]
  # programmatically assemble regression formula
  regressionFormula <- as.formula(
    paste("Bound_Count ~ ", paste(currentvariable, collapse="+")))
  # fit model
  currentModel <- glm(formula = regressionFormula, family=binomial(link = "logit"), data=dataL_TT)
  # store model in container
  listOfModels[[i]] <- currentModel
} 
listOfModels
```

So basically I just want to automate the d <- data.frame to input/replace other variables in it. Not just by manually replacing each one of them to a new variable.
I have been trying the code below but it does not work.

```
#Automate variable names trial
Y <- dataL$Bound_Count
X1 <- dataL$Days_diff_Eff_Subm_2
X2 <- dataL$TR_BS_BROKER_ID_360_M
X3 <- dataL$TR_BS_BROKER_ID_360_2
X4 <- dataL$RURALPOP_P_CWR_2
X5 <- dataL$RURALPOP_P_CWR_M
X6 <-  dataL$PIP_Flag
X7 <- dataL$TR_B_BROKER_ID_360
X8 <- dataL$TR_SCW_BROKER_ID_360
X9  <- dataL$TR_BS_BROKER_INDIVIDUAL_720_2
X10 <- dataL$TR_BS_BROKER_INDIVIDUAL_720_M
X11 <- dataL$Resolved_Conflict
X12 <- dataL$Priority_2

d <- data.frame(Y = 1, X1 = 2, X2 = 3, 
                X3= 4, X4 = 5, X5 = 6, X6 = 7, 
                X7 = 8, X8 = 9, X9 = 10,
                X10 = 11, X11 = 12, 
                X12 = 13)
# exclude target variable
allvariables <- names(d)[-1] 
# container for models
listOfModels <- vector("list", length(allvariables))
# loop over variables
for (i in seq_along(allvariables)) {
  # exclude variable i
  currentvariable <- allvariables[-i]
  # programmatically assemble regression formula
  regressionFormula <- as.formula(
    paste("Bound_Count ~ ", paste(currentvariable, collapse="+")))
  # fit model
  currentModel <- glm(formula = regressionFormula, family=binomial(link = "logit"), data=dataL_TT)
  # store model in container
  listOfModels[[i]] <- currentModel
} 
listOfModels
```

Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Your code is not reproductible .. what is  `dataL_TT ` ? And what do you intend to do ? **ust want to automate the d <- data.frame to input/replace other variables in it. Not just by manually replacing each one of them to a new variable** is not clear for me ..

Comment: May be you are interested by `dredge` ?

Comment: If you guys see my 2nd set of codes. How can I make that work?? Because it outputs an error. It should output the same thing on the 1st set of codes. Thanks.